# XAML Best Practices Guideline

Tags: silverlight, xaml

I have a large Silverlight application, and we have decided to redesign the whole interface. Since it is a good time to polish some issues, I would like to read some XAML good practices to take into account when designing.

Does anyone know of a good Silverlight (or even WPF) book or guide to read about XAML? I'm not looking for a tutorial on XAML, I just want to know some good practices.

Thanks!

Comment: I thought I remembered something similar to this, but all I can find right now is centered around Prism.  Skim this, it might give you some  ideas...http://www.codeplex.com/CompositeWPF

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a good link having video interview with people who have worked with wpf and silverlight (XAML) a lot  http://dotnet.org.za/rudi/archive/2009/01/13/xaml-guidelines-released.aspx